Change bold font weight in VS Code
In VS Code, some lexemes like class names are rendered as bold. I have downloaded some awesome monospaced variable fonts from Google Fonts. I can change the normal font weight using editor.fontWeight, but there is not such an option like editor.fontWeightBold. Now my question is if it is possible to change it or not?

This doesn't exist even for token highlighting customization (see Allow setting font weights or semibold/thin/heavy... in fontStyle in tokenColors #145018).
This is the subject of feature requests like

Specific weight for regular and bold #207919
Allow setting editor.fontWeightBold #110863

I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".
